# How change color of item in three.js gui

Tags: user-interface, three.js, webgl, dat.gui

How to write item with a specific color in three.js gui menu. Or add a square or circle with a speficic color before a item menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to dat.gui ? If so, then this is a separate software library from three.js, and instead you can read about all the capabilities at:

http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage

As far as I know, there is no way to add decorations as you mentioned to dat.gui.